# NSPredicate to detect an entire set of entities being present in multiple entity relationships

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

Given a core data entity setup like this

- Entity **A**

  - aB -> **B** (many to 1)
  - aC -> **C** (many to 1)
  - children -> **Child** (many to many)
- Entity **B**

  - children -> **Child** (many to many)
- Entity **C**

  - children -> **Child** (many to many)
- Entity **Child**

I'm trying to do a query to find all Entity **A**'s such that a set of Child entities **TestChildren** is found across all the reachable Children. Something like this example for a matching **A** entity, **A1**

- **TestChildren** Set

  - **Child1**
  - **Child2**
  - **Child3**
  - **Child4**
- **A1** Entity

  - aB -> **B1**
  - aC -> **C1**
  - children

    - -> **child1**
    - -> **child3**
- **B1** Entity

  - children

    - -> **child2**
- **C1** Entity

  - children

    - -> **child4**

So all 4 children have been found across the various children relationships in each class.

It seems that to test for these sets I have to perform subqueries over each Children relationship, but I don't think I can express what I want with the NSPredicate format.. perhaps its just not doable at all with NSPredicates?

An idea I had was to do something like this

```
  predicateString += "((SUBQUERY(aB.children, $child, $child in %@).@count + SUBQUERY(aC.children, $child, $child in %@).@count + SUBQUERY(children, $child, $child in $@).@count) == $@)"
  predicateVars.append(contentsOf: [testChildren, testChildren, testChildren, testChildren.count])
```

Where the total of matching counts across all the children relationships have to match.. unfortunately if the same child could be present in more than one A,B, or C then this wouldn't be correct as the same child matched in two different classes would allow the total to incorrectly match.

Regardless it seems that adding up counts is not something that is even possible in NSPredicates?

The only way to really do this properly is to be able to generate a total set of all children across the 3 classes, but again there doesn't seem to be a way to express this in an NSPredicate?

Worse case I can do a simpler query and perform more logic on the returned results, but ideally I'd try to do as much heavy lifting as possible in the query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If all children relationships are one-to-many then a child can't be present in more than one A, B or C. Do you want to check if all A's of the TestChildren are the same A? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake with the description.. I've amended it now. Apologies.. its A -> B, and A->C are both many to 1 relationships and all the children are many to many, as you can see more clearly in the original question text now.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I've added another question working with a similar but slightly different hierarchy of entities here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753032/nspredicate-to-detect-non-empty-relationships-within-a-subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicate to find all A's with a child:

```
NSPredicate(format:"aB.children contains %@ OR aC.children contains %@ OR children contains %@", child, child, child)
```

AND predicate to find all A's with `child1` and `child2` and `child3` and `child4`:

```
var predicateArray:[NSPredicate] = []
for child in testChildren {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"aB.children contains %@ OR aC.children contains %@ OR children contains %@", child, child, child)
    predicateArray.append(predicate)
}
let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I’ll have a go with it tomorrow and if i can get it working I’ll accept the answer! Fingers crossed! Cheers!

Comment: This worked great. I ended up redoing it as a string predicate instead of a compound one, I presume they're equivalent and the string is easier to debug later on as you can read the entire predicate. I'll put my version in another answer, but I've accepted yours. It is strange why we have to handle each child individually, when I read the NSPredicate docs it looked like you should be able to work with containers of entities as I was trying to do. But no matter what I tried I couldn't get it working, where as this worked great!

Comment: What are the limits on these predicates i wonder.. in string form I did wonder how far you could push it, similarly with the compound predicate, luckily I wouldn't expect there to ever be more than a handful of children to be processed this way.. its not like its going to go to 10s or 100s of them which would just be a mess

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version of Willeke's answer above is to build the predicates described as strings with variables as shown here

```
var predicateString:String = ""
var predicateVars:[Any] = []

for child in testChildren
{
  if (predicateString.count > 0)
  {
    predicateString += " && "
  }

  predicateString += "(aB.children contains %@ || aC.children contains %@ || children contains %@)"
  predicateVars.append(contentsOf: [child, child, child])
}
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateString, argumentArray: predicateVars)
```