# NSPredicate to detect non-empty relationships within a subquery

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

Given a core data entity setup as follows

- Entity A

  - Bs -> B (many to many)
  - Cs -> C (many to many)
  - children -> Child (many to many)
- Entity B

  - children -> Child (many to many)
- Entity C

  - children -> Child (many to many)
- Child

  - date

I've wanted to query for Entity A's where any of the children (in Entity A, B, or C) have dates that pass some query like being greater than a specified date.

Given the nested relationships some nested subqueries were required, so for checking all the Bs children from A with something like this

```
predicateString += "(SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, SUBQUERY($b.children, $child, $child.date >= %@).@count > 0).@count > 0)"
predicateVars = [testDate! as NSDate]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateString, argumentArray: predicateVars)
```

Repeating the same form of query for Cs and then just doing a single SUBQUERY for A's direct children.

This all works fine after some fine tuning of the predicate form (ensuring all the required counts were added).

The small problem arose when I wanted to now perform a similar search but instead of requiring the children's date to be greater than a test date I wanted to just find all A's who had any children in either A.children, Bs.children, Cs.children.

The nested SUBQUERIES caused problems, at first I thought it'd be fine to do a single level SUBQUERY and then check the count of the children relationship within it, so something like this

```
predicateString += " SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, $b.children.@count > 0).@count > 0"
```

Which is accepted as a valid predicate but when its evaluated you hit an exception

```
[error] error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60000018ec70> , Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $b.children.@count with userInfo of (null)
```

A quick search of stack overflow came up with the same error in this question

[Keypath error with Core Data SUBQUERY and NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762539/keypath-error-with-core-data-subquery-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Which seemed to suggest that you cannot do the @count within a SUBQUERY and therefore have to do another SUBQUERY over the children to get at the same result. Which would be the same form as my first example above, albeit I need a condition in my SUBQUERY that is always true for each element of the children. My first thought was hopefully that I could just use TRUE like this

```
predicateString += "(SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, SUBQUERY($b.children, $child, TRUE).@count > 0).@count > 0)"
```

It feels quite wasteful, but would do what I wanted. Unfortunately it fails to parse as a valid predicate.

Beyond this I have managed to succeed by making queries that should always be true, so comparing the date against 1970 as follows

```
let date1970 = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
predicateString += "(SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, SUBQUERY($b.children, $child, $child.date >= %@).@count > 0).@count > 0)"
predicateVars = [date1970! as NSDate]
```

This works, but feels like doing a bit more work than I'd prefer to just get a count. A simpler example that works is also just testing each child against nil, so

```
predicateString += "(SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, SUBQUERY($b.children, $child, $child != nil).@count > 0).@count > 0)"
predicateVars = [testDate! as NSDate]
```

This seems much better but I just wondered if there was a better option. I honestly don't understand why the TRUE condition alone isn't a valid predicate.. yes its wasteful, but it seems in this case we must do an effectively wasteful subquery to get the count we want.

Anyone got any better ideas?

Comment: My only suggestion, with no idea whether it will work, is to test the children relationship != nil, rather than testing each child: `SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, $b.children != nil).@count > 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd not tried it and it doesn't seem unreasonable. Sadly having just tried it I can confirm that whilst it makes a valid predicate, when i performFetch on my fetchedResultsController using the predicate it throws this exception. "CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000380270> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)". I don't think there's any way around it, you seemingly have to subquery through to get a count of all the elements.